# Stack Overflow Snippets for Sublime Text

Tags: app, editing

### About:

This is a utility for the *Sublime Text* editor.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> in your Sublime Text, enter a search query, and get code snippets from the matched questions.

**Screenshot / Code Snippet:**

[image: Demo]

#### Download

Install via [Package Control (*Stack Overflow Snippets*)](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Stack%20Overflow%20Snippets).

#### Platform

*Sublime Text* 2/3

### Contact

ringaud@gmail.com

### Code

It's [on GitHub at *StackOverflowSnippets*](https://github.com/rinas7/StackOverflowSnippets).